# How to declare variable into a route name in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I want to pass a variable to a route('video.' . $video['video_id']);

Here's my route on controller..

```
Route::get('/video/{id}', array('as' => 'video', 'uses' => 'VideoController@show'));
```

Is it possible to do it like

```
Route::get('/video/{id}', array('as' => 'video.{id}', 'uses' => 'VideoController@show'));
```

somehow?

Comment: I don't think route names were ever intended to be dynamic. Even if it is possible, I think it's abusing the system.

Comment: Please explain why it'll abuse the system.

Comment: Because named routes were intended to be invoked with the route name and parameters sent as an array

Comment: Keep the route name static and just add a parameter while loading/redirecting to the route while accessing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The entire idea behind named routes is that you can always refer to a route by its name, even if you change the URI or controller/method it uses. This means that that name should be a constant, invariable string. If you want to inject a variable into the route, you should use route parameters.

If you set up your route declaration like this:

```
Route::get('/video/{id}', array('as' => 'video', 'uses' => 'VideoController@show'));
```

And then you can build your routes like this:

```
<a href="{{URL::route('video', array($id))}}">Thing</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is, in fact, abusing the system, but just for the sake of it being possible to link to routes dynamically, for example in a loop, having declared routes for

```
$menus = ["Clients", "Invoices"];
```

having alias **Clients_manage** and **Invoices_manage**, you can do for example a loop on **$menus** in your templates, like this:

```
@foreach($menus as $modelname)
<a href="{{route($modelname."_manage")}}">Manage {{$modelname}}</a>
@endforeach
```